# Wildcard Search in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

Can someone please help me with the following wildcard search criteria in MongoDB ?
Document:

```
{"path":"foo/bar/{id}/somethingelse"}
```

or

```
{"path":"foo/bar/*/somethingelse"}
```

So I want to get this document when a find request something like this comes:

```
db.collection.find({path:"foo/bar/1/somethingelse"})
```

or

```
db.collection.find({path:"foo/bar/2/somethingelse"})
```

So if the document has got some wildcard, I want to match it for a criteria matching that pattern.

Answer (score 2):

For wildcards like this, you can use regex which would look something like:

```
db.collection.find({"path": new RegExp("foo/bar/.*?/somethingelse")})
```

But if I understand your question correctly, you have a **single** document in your collection with a path of `{"path":"foo/bar/{id}/somethingelse"}` and you want to return it if the query is actually for `db.collection.find({path:"foo/bar/1/somethingelse"})`. To do this, its likely best that you do search replaces prior to the search to change the actual query like so.

```
path = path.replace(/foo\/bar\/(.*)\/somethingelse/, 'foo/bar/{id}/somethingelse')
db.collection.find({path:path})
```

Hope this helps!

---

**edit based on comments**

To do a reverse wildcard match the following should work, returning the requested document and any matching wildcards. You'll need to define what each *actual* wildcards are for this to work.

```
path.replace(/foo\/bar\/(.*)\/somethingelse/, 'foo/bar/($1|{id}|\*)/somethingelse')
db.collection.find({path: new RegExp(path)})
```

Comment: Collection can have multiple documents, like {"path":"foo/*/bar/somethingelse"} so in this case db.collection.find({path:"foo/1/bar/somethingelse"}) should fetch the result; basically I want reverse wildcard.